# If a function is Frechet differentiable, does the Frechet derivative equal the Gateaux derivative?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

If a function is Frechet differentiable, does the Frechet derivative equal the Gateaux derivative?

Comment: Are you speaking only of functions between normed spaces, or general topological vector spaces? (Not that it changes the answer, which is "Yes", but the general case is a little messier to write down.)

Comment: Only normed spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function $f \colon U \to Y$, where $U \subset X$ is open, is Fréchet differentiable in $x \in U$ with (Fréchet) derivative $L$, iff we have

$$f(x+h) - f(x) - L(h) \in o(\lVert h\rVert).$$

So for the Gâteaux derivative, we have, for any $v \in X$,

$$\frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t} - L(v) = \frac{f(x+tv) - f(x) - L(tv)}{t} = \pm\frac{f(x+tv) - f(x) - L(tv)}{\lVert tv\rVert}\lVert v\rVert,$$

and the right hand side tends to $0$ for $t\to 0$ since $t\to 0$ implies $\lVert tv\rVert \to 0$.

Thus Fréchet differentiability implies Gâteaux differentiability, and the Gâteaux derivative then coincides with the Fréchet derivative.