# If $f:\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $a\in\mathbb R^p$, then function $g:R\to R$ defined by $g(t)=f(a+th)$ has a derivative at t=0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem is: Show that if $f:\mathbb R^p \to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $a \in\mathbb R^p$, then show that, for each fixed $ h \in\mathbb R^p$, the function $g :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(t) = f(a + th)$ has a derivative at $t = 0$.

Since we are given that f is differentiable at $a$ while $g(t)$ at $t=0$ is basically $f(a)$, it would make sense to assume that $g(0)$ is differentiable, but there are some technical points that needs to be worked out when defining the derivative here and that is where I am running into some problem. By the definition of the derivative for multivariable functions, since f is differentiable at $a$, we have $$\lim_{||h||\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah}{||h||} \to 0$$ where $A$ is the linear map from $R^p$  to $R$. We need to show that $g(t)$ is differentiable at $0$ so $$\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)-g'(0)h}{||h||}$$ approaches 0 as $h$ approaches $0$.

Now there are some slight issues with trying to transform the bottom difference quotient to the top one. First $g(0+h)$ is $f(a+(0+h)h)=f(a+h^2)$ and I am not sure if something like $h^2$ is even defined since $h$ is in $R^p$ and we have not introduced any notion of vector multiplication on the vector space. Also, the $h$ in the difference quotient with $g$ is in fact an element of R while the $h$ in the quotient with $f$ is an element of $R^p$ so they are not the same thing.

Comment: Do not use the letter $h$ again.

Comment: Thanks. I was confusing myself with the notations

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533172/if-a-function-is-frechet-differentiable-does-the-frechet-derivative-equal-the-g) help? There's a bit of extra terminology but the fundamental ideas are there.

Comment: Did you try rewriting the question without using the letter $h$ when discussing derivatives? $h\in\Bbb R^p$ is FIXED.

Comment: Just use Chain rule to show $g^\prime(0)=\langle \nabla f(a), a\rangle$.